# 401 Unauthorized Error while loading report through reportviewer in .net website hosted on azure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, reporting-services, report-viewer2010

I have .net website hosted on azure. In that, I am trying to load a report using reportviewer control but i am getting the 401 unauthorize error on load within a minute or 2. I check the azure logs to see the full stack trace error but no log present over there. Then i check the reportserver log files and i found the following stack trace

```html
ERROR: Reporting Services error Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerHttpRuntimeClientDisconnectionException: A client has disconnected from the Report Server Web service application domain ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER_0-1-130692380425542626. No corrective action is required. An error code has been submitted to ASP.NET to release the connection. The error code is 800708CA. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800708CA): This network connection does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708CA)
```

The records are around 1,50,000 and above. However, sometime it is getting loaded perfectly.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reportviewer control relies on session state to maintain details of the report as it's built, and paged. I'm not certain about the details of how azure works but with load balanced servers, I've had to configure a separate Session Server database to allow it to maintain state as it switches from server to server.

Managing session

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/05/17/session-state-management-in-windows-azure-web-roles.aspx

Report viewer and session

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2009/02/15/did-your-session-really-expire.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon. But it seems that this error is occuring intermittent. Some time the page get loaded successfully. But sometimes it get stuck. My session state is inproc by defaut and session timout will be 20 minutes. Please provide me any ideas if u have regarding this error.

Comment: Your session is tied to the server running your page. With azure your requests aren't going to always go to the same server. You will be hitting different servers depending on load. Sometimes you will hit the original server where your session is valid, but you can't rely on it.

Comment: I agree to your point regarding session management. However, before modifying this report the record count was 142744 and it was getting loaded properly. But after modifying this report by adding 2 columns i am facing this issue. Now the record count is 157217. If it is session issue then sometime it should have failed for old report also.

Comment: Agreed, maybe the extra columns & rows are causing the report to timeout in some sense. Sorry all out of ideas after that.